# Find row/column from Key in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this one:

```
                                                       0          1            2   \
0                                                 NaN        NaN          NaN   
1              CITI Pass-T...                     NaN        NaN   
2                                                 NaN        NaN          NaN   
3              Certificateholder Distribution Summary        NaN          NaN   
4                                               Class      CUSIP  Record Date   
5                                                 A-1  25151EAA1   12/30/2016   
6                                                 A-2  25151EAB9   12/30/2016   
7                                                 A-3  25151EAC7   12/30/2016   
8                                                 A-4  25151EAD5   12/30/2016   
9                                                A-5A  25151EAE3   12/30/2016   
10                                               A-5B  25151EAF0   12/30/2016   
11                                                A-6  25151EAG8   12/30/2016   
12                                                A-7  25151EAH6   12/30/2016   
13                                                A-8  25151EAJ2   01/24/2017   
14                                                M-1  25151EAK9   12/30/2016   
15                                                M-2  25151EAL7   12/30/2016   
16                                                M-3  25151EAM5   12/30/2016   
17                                                M-4  25151EAN3   12/30/2016   
18                                                M-5  25151EAP8   12/30/2016   
19                                                M-6  25151EAQ6   12/30/2016   
20                                                M-7  25151EAR4   12/30/2016   
21                                                M-8  25151EAS2   12/30/2016   
22                                                M-9  25151EAT0   12/30/2016   
23                                               M-10  25151EAU7   12/30/2016   
24                                               M-11  25151EAV5   12/30/2016   
25                                                  P  25151EAX1   12/30/2016   
26                                                 CE  25151EAW3   12/30/2016   
27                                                  R  25151EAY9   12/30/2016   
28                                             Totals        NaN          NaN   
29  This report is compiled by me, N...                      NaN          NaN   
30  All Record Dates are based upon the governing ...        NaN          NaN   
31                                                NaN        NaN          NaN
```

So you see, there are no real column headers. Now I want for example search for the value A-1.

It can be, that the value A-1 is twice or even more times in the DF.

I wanted to use the get_loc function:

```
df.index.get_loc('A1',method='nearest')]
```

Then I get the following error:

```
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4433)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 156, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4363)
KeyError: 'A-1'
```

So I guess it is not possible to apply the get_loc function on this DF.

Does anyone have a idea to solve this or do I need to do a column or row-wise search?

Comment: does `df[df[0] == 'A1', 0]` work?

Comment: I am getting this: TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Comment: Try `df[df['0'] == 'A1', '0']`

Comment: Then we are back to my original error:   File "pandas/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4433)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 156, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4363)
KeyError: '0'